# Where to store connection string for WCF service that uses EF

Tags: sharepoint-server, wcf

I have a WCF service deployed to ISAPI that uses EntityFramework, however, I cannot find where and how can I store the connection string so it can be automatically retrieved when the DBContext is initialized in the application constructor of entity framework initialization, specifically,  base("name=ConnectionStringName").

PS: The deployed WCF project doesn't have a web.config

Regards

Comment: How was your WCF developed? Besides the ConnectionString, a number of things go into WCF web.config file. If you generate EntityFramework model using VS, it automatically adds the connection string to the web.config. You can update that to point to a different SQL server as it  moves from DEV, TEST, UAT and to PROD

Comment: Legacy code. On top of that, it uses code first.

Answer (score 0):

Even it's code first, you will have a "Context" class inherited from DbContext.
In the base class you can refer connection string name in the web.config file:

```
 public class Context: DbContext 
    {
        public MyDBContext() : base("name=MyDBConnectionString") 
        {
        }
    }
```

And connectionstring can be stored in the web.config like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=MyDataServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalogDB;Integrated Security=true" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```